# eigendecomposition(A = V.D. V^-1) of symmetric matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, eigenvector, decomposition

Hi

I want to compute eig-decomposition of symmetric matrix A in matlab. assume that A = V.D. V^-1(standard form ).

I checked `eig(A)` and `svd(A)` but `svd` give me A = U.s.V which U and V are not orthonormal (U.V != I).

and also there is a approximately same problem for `eig(A)`

Is there any way that I can find standard form in Matlab?

I would appreciate your solutions.

Comment: If you want `U`, `S`, `V` with `U` and `V` orthonormal (unitary), maybe what you need is the singular value decomposition ([`svd`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html))

Comment: @Ander Biguri yes it is true! the documentation doesn't say that, but if we assume the documentation  instead your comment doesn't give an effective solution and I don't understand why you think my question is not useful

Comment: @Captain `eig(A)` worked as expected for me. Perhaps you can give us a small example that gives incorrect results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `eig(A)` computes invertible `V`, you can use 
`Vinv=V^(-1);`.

Thus you obtain 
`A= V * D * Vinv`

I would suggest you to read according literature first, then ask further or again.
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node31.html
The according book is okay, a really good paper for a general overview is "Eigenvalue computation in the 20th century".